# To select multiple lines from the List in Data Validation in MS Excel

Tags: excel

I have inserted following code so that I can select multiple lines to a single cell C14, D14 and E14 from the Data validation List.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String

On Error GoTo Exitsub
Target.Address = "$C$14" Or Target.Address = "$D$14" Or Target.Address = "$E$14" Then
    If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
    Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Newvalue = Target.Value
        Application.Undo
        Oldvalue = Target.Value
        If Oldvalue = "" Then
            Target.Value = Newvalue
        Else
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
        End If
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Sorry for noob question. How shall the Concatenation be so that Newvalue appears in next line rather in same line.
The code needs some tweeting here I think.
`Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue`

Thanks for some hints please.

Answer (score 0):

changed the code as follows:-

```
Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
```